# How to get request from android to my django views?

Tags: python, android, django, sqlite

I need to link my Django models with an Android app.

I have to get data which send from the Android application to my Django views. Also, I need to compare the data that exist in my Django model, but I don't know how do I get the response.

Comment: what have you tried so far? http request would be an option. Write an API (you can use the DRF) and implement your logic. Your website needs to be public for that case.

Comment: I use following code '    if request.method=='GET':
        eusername=request.GET.get('eusername')
        x=elogdb.objects.all()
        for i in x:
            if i.eusername==eusername :
                return  HttpResponse('success')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('failed')'   I am a fresherdeveloper.I have no previous experience for get/post request. I don't know whether it is correct or not.When i run this code it return failed only.